# $X_n$ converges weakly to $δ_p$, then $X_n \to p$ in probability.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

To prove that if $(S, d)$ is a metric space, $p \in S$ and $X_n$ are random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$ such that the law of $X_n$ converges weakly to $δ_p$, then $X_n \to p$ in probability.

Here $\delta_p(S) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } p \in S \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Require some hints to proceed with the problem.

Comment: You can start with what it means for the law of $X_n$ to converge weakly to $\delta_p$.  Also, state what you want to show, that is, what is needed to prove $X_n\rightarrow p$ in probability?

Comment: This question has been already asked for several times; you might consider using the search (in particular, since you are not providing any personal input).